# Compare values in a row of three columns and replace with NULL if equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

See the table below:

| Price_one | Price_two | Price_three | Price_four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204 | 204 | 204 | 204 |
| 208 | 208 | 208 | 208 |
| 212 | 212 | 212 | 212 |
| 206 | 195 | 187 | 204 |

My data provider does this weird thing that if the price is unavailable it just copies the value from **Price_one** to the rest of the columns. What I want to do is to replace the equal rows of **Price_two**, **Price_three**, and **Price_four** with just `NULL`s, so that I would get the refurbished table below:

| Price_one | Price_two | Price_three | Price_four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 208 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 212 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 206 | 195 | 187 | 204 |

So **Price_one** stays and the rows with unequal values also stay. It is essential that in order for the value to be replaced by NULL, all three prices need to be equal to each other; if just two are, then they should remain so.
Is that feasible in SQL?

Comment: [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: On Postgres, I would use the array functions to aggregate the prices. I don't know if sql-server can do that easily.

Comment: Do you want to update the table or just select the values as described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename
    WHERE Price_one   = Price_two
      AND Price_two   = Price_three
      AND Price_three = Price_four
)
UPDATE cte SET Price_two   = NULL, 
               Price_three = NULL, 
               Price_four  = NULL;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d576a4b11247386a3cc76184ea78cebc)

I like the CTE approach because, for more complex queries, it makes it very easy to replace the DML action with a SELECT to be sure you're affecting the right rows. In this situation we can also just write a direct UPDATE:

```
UPDATE dbo.tablename
  SET Price_two   = NULL, 
      Price_three = NULL, 
      Price_four  = NULL
    WHERE Price_one   = Price_two
      AND Price_two   = Price_three
      AND Price_three = Price_four;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a1b796c7820b534ac8e1f54b63b27d0)